# Need a way to alert users when building spotify app

Tags: api, spotify

I'm building a spotify app that does some work in the background and should then alert the user if it finds a match. I can't find a way to notify the user on the main plane when I have found something of interest.

I'd like to have something like a counter on my app name or some form of notification in order to alert the user that something has changed in my app and that they should come to the app.

Does anyone know if this is possible ?

thanks,

Sean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to notify them via Facebook, Spotify doesn't allow you to identify the individual users on the Spotify platform through the api.

Answer (score 0):

Also there is the issue of that your App unloads after 60seconds of the user not being on the App Pane (off in a playlist etc).

So whilst a counter icon that you suggest would be wonderful.
The App Unload-er needs to go away first.